# iPhone UIImagePickerController file name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

after getting a selected image in `didFinishPickingImage:`, is there a way to get the filename or name of that image? Is there any string that uniquely identifies that image or that is saved with the image at the moment image was added to the photo album?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the metadata, but from my tests the title does not seem to be there or anywhere else.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I couldn't find anything either, but this really sucks.